Scrapy - one spider, two pipelines. How to decide which one will be used?
I have a spider that processes data from a website. On this website, there are products and manufacturers. The structure of the spider looks like this:
import scrapy
from sreality.itemsloaders import ProductLoader, ManufacturerLoader
from sreality.items import Product, Manufacturer

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  ...
  custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'proj.pipelines.ProductPipeline': 400,
            'proj.pipelines.ManufacturerPipeline': 300
        }
    }
  ...
  def parse(self, response):
    data_product = ProductLoader(item=Product(), selector=response)
    ...
    data_manufacturer = ManufacturerLoader(item=Manufacturer(), selector=response)
    ...
    yield data_product.load_item() # I want this to be processed by ProductPipeline
    yield data_manufacturer.load_item() # and this by ManufacturerPipeline

pipelines.py
class ProductPipeline:
  def process_item(self, item):
    ...

class ManufacturerPipeline:
  def process_item(self, item):
    ...

If I run this code, then the data from data_manufacturer will be saved through the ManufacturerPipeline, but then it will through an error in the ProductPipeline that some database attributes do not exist (which is understandable).
What I am trying to achieve is the following:

spider runs -> gets data to data_manufacturer and product_manufacturer.
data_manufacturer gets saved to ManufacturerPipeline
data_product gets saved to ProductPipeline

I don't want data_manufacturer to be sent through ProductPipeline and data_product through ManufacturerPipeline. Is there any way to achieve it?

As plan B, I can have one big pipeline where I could process a lot of data, but I think if I can specify which batches of data can be sent to specific pipelines, so I could be cleaner.

Does this answer your question? Scrapy, Python: Multiple Item Classes in one pipeline?
